# A "Dilation" with a Complex Number

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a mapping $w(z) = 2iz$, where $z \in \{z\in\mathbb{C} : x > 0, |y| < 1 \}$. My goal is to find the image set under this mapping. At first, I thought that this was simply a dilation, but then I realized that under the definition of a dilation that I'm working with, the constant must be a positive real number (which it is clearly not in this case, since $2i$ is a complex number). So this mapping is not a dilation. Can I simply consider $z = x + yi$ and then do $2iz = 2i(x + yi) = 2ix - 2y$ to determine my image set, or there something else I need to do instead?

Comment: Note:  multiplication by $i$ is a $90^\circ$ rotation

Comment: That is basically it.  You have half-a-strip in the complex plane.  Rotate as @J.W.Tanner indicates, and dilate it to a half-strip of double width.

Comment: Ah, that's what I was missing. That makes so much more sense now. Thank you.

Comment: Also, your algebraic solution is correct:  $2iz=-2y+2ix, \quad |y|<1 \Rightarrow | \Re \{2iz\} |<2, \quad x>0 \Rightarrow \Im \{ 2iz \} >0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

$$w = a+ib = 2iz = -2y+2ix$$

$$|y|<1 \Rightarrow |a|<2, \quad x>0 \Rightarrow b>0.$$